# Get a number in one table and print the number's referenced name in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a friend system, but my loop always skips the first match and sometimes it prints copies of the same name

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbusers INNER JOIN tbfriends ON tbusers.id = tbfriends.username_id");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
if ($row['username_id'] == 1)//the 1 will be a variable, username_id is in friends    
$count = $row['friendname'];//friendname is in friends      
if ($row['id'] == $count)//id is in users    
echo $row['username'];//username is in users
}
```

Can someone see what my problem is ?

Answer (score 2):

2 things:

```
if ($row['username_id'] == 1)
```

you should put that in your sql:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username, friendname FROM tbusers INNER JOIN tbfriends ON tbusers.id = tbfriends.username_id where tbusers.id = ".$yourVariable);
```

In your query, user and friend are linked, and can only be equal.

Now, this:

```
$count = $row['friendname'];//friendname is in friends      
if ($row['id'] == $count)//id is in users
```

is equal to

```
if ( $row['id'] == $row['friendname'] )
```

this sounds plain wrong. You compare a numerical id with a name. Moreover, your sql query already retrives all friends from users. In the version I showed here, it retrieves only friends of the user you are interested in.

finally, you print (echo) the name of the user, not of the friend. In my opinion the following code will do what you want:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT friendname FROM tbfriends WHERE username_id = ".$yourUserVariable);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
  echo $row['friendname']; //  or better: echo $row['friendname'], '<br>'; 
}
```

edit: after comment...

so `if ( $row['id'] == $row['friendname'] )` means the user is his own friend. can that happen?

this code shall print what you want, friend names.

```
/*
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT username as friend_name, 
           friendname as friend_id,
           username_id as user_id
    FROM tbusers INNER JOIN tbfriends ON tbusers.id = tbfriends.username_id 
    WHERE tbusers.id = ".$yourVariable);
```

*/

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT username as friend_name, 
           friendname as friend_id,
           username_id as user_id
    FROM tbusers INNER JOIN tbfriends ON tbusers.id = tbfriends.friendname 
    WHERE tbfriends.username_id = ".$yourVariable);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo $row['friend_name']; //  or better: echo $row['friend_name'], '<br>'; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention friendname is also an id. The person's info is in the users table. The friends table is used to check which persons are friends, so your solution work but I only get the ids of the friens that's why I had if ( $row['id'] == $row['friendname'] )

Comment: my head hurts ^^'! you should rename friendname into friend_id, for sake of readability? As well. tbfriends.username_id should be renamed to user_id.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Some name are still duplicate and some name that should appear first doesn't.

Comment: Ignore the previous comment. It still doesn't work. Some name are still duplicate and some name that should appear first doesn't. Ok this is the layout of the tables. tbusers: id, username,... tbfriends: user_id, friend_id(these ids correspond to tbusers' id in tbusers) How would I get it to work ? If it's still unclear just ask

Comment: I did update my last sql query (and commented out the previous one). It now retrieves friends name of the $variable, instead of the user name! Sorry to not have spotted it sooner :/